# cross domain issue in sharepoint 2013 while accessing sharepoint list items using Ajax

Tags: cors

i have written Rest Ajax call to fetch sharepoint 2013 list items from another sitecollection which works fine in IE but when same in chrome throws error CORS, cross domain issue.

Am looking for solution in client-slide solution where we don't have option to change/modify web.config or server-side solution.

Appreciated for suggestions and solutions. Thanks in advance